# The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

this is my code

**ProductController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    product productx = productDB.products.Single(pr => pr.Product1 == id);
    return View(productx);


}
```

**Details.aspx**

```
    <td>
        <%-- : Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) % --> 
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Product1 })%>
    </td>
```

this is what im using to list some products from a sql database, each product have a link to a Details page to show more informations about it

what Im trying is to only put the product label in that link to let it show something like **www.mysite.com\products\battery** (not the id)

I've imagined this should work, but it throw an **The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.** error and 
neither `(pr => pr.Product1.Equals(id));` works

the error is clear and Im asking how should I do to make it work this way ?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888243/the-data-types-text-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator-in-c-s)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[TEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) columns in SQL Server are considered Large Object data and therefore aren't indexable/searchable.  They're also deprecated.  So, actually, the problem is in your database, not in your application.

If you change the column type to a `varchar(max)`, you can store the same amount of character data but shouldn't have this problem.  Then, update your Linq to SQL entity, and you'll no longer get this particular error.

Having said that... a column named `ID` shouldn't be `TEXT` **or** `varchar(max)`, it should be an auto-increment integer ID or a GUID (`uniqueidentifier`), so you might want to revisit your DB design.  But assuming you have good reasons for IDs to be string values of arbitrary size, the above change will allow you to filter on the column.

Comment: Thanks! it works by setting it to varchar(max), another little question : how about the way im returning the productx, is that a best practice ?

Comment: @metro: The way you're returning the `Product` is fine.  But if we're talking about best practices, you *really* should consider using a different data type for the ID; you'll run into *major* performance problems with large character types.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can to occur then use:

**Exemple**

```
string sql = "Select * from TB_USER where Name = @Name";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
```

**This is incompatible:**

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.Text).Value = nome;
```

**Change for:**

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = nome;
```