# EF6 Querying for the string with newline character

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

How do I query a string in EF6 that has a newline character (\n) in it? For example, I have a string `$"Hello {Environment.Newline} World"`.

Now I have to find it using Linq, so I'm trying to find it with the following query: (I want to find it using the exact same string with special characters)

```
GetEntities<TimeEntry>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.WorkDescription == $"Hello \r\n World")
```

The code above throws an exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.'
>   Inner exception: SqlException: The data types nvarchar and text are
>   incompatible in the equal to operator.

So how should we fix it? Is there any possibility to avoid special characters?

PS. There is a strong restriction for using ToList() methods, we want to avoid it as much as possible and ideally, everything should be done using IQueryable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726649/the-data-types-text-and-nvarchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator

Answer (score 1):

Construct the string before the linq call:

```
string workDescription = $"Hello {Environment.Newline} World";
GetEntities<TimeEntry>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.WorkDescription == workDescription);
```

Comment: Why? What does this change, and how would this make that work?